# How to get the nth value and key of a Sass list?

Tags: sass

How to get nth item (value, key) of list in SASS?

Let's say that exists following list:

```
$list: ( 
  'foo1': 11,
  'foo2': 22,
  'foo3': 33
);
```

I want to get for example 2nd item to have:

```
$2nd-key: 'foo2';
$2nd-value: 22;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not a list, it's a map. So you can [use map functions to extract a value or a key](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#map_get-instance_method). There are many interesting functions and work very well with loops.

To answer your question, you could use for example 2 of these functions ([`map-keys()`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map#keys) & [`map-values()`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map#values)) to create a list of keys and values from your map and than use the [`nth()`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/list#nth) function to get your desired value or key:

```
$map: ( 
  'foo1': 11,
  'foo2': 22,
  'foo3': 33
);

div{
  content:nth(map-keys($map), 2);
  z-index:nth(map-values($map), 2);
}
```

The output:

```
div {
  content: "foo2";
  z-index: 22;
}
```

`nth()` tells Sass to step through each value of the map. Otherwise, you'd just assign the first value of the map, `11`, to each variable in your list (if there were multiple variables).